# Simple SQL many-to-many query

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm really new to SQL so I want to ask for your help:

Here are my tables:

```
orders:
+----------+-------------+--------+
| order_id | customer_id | amount |
+----------+-------------+--------+
|        1 |           1 |  19.99 |
|        2 |           2 |  35.15 |
|        3 |           3 |  17.56 |
|        4 |           4 |  12.34 |
+----------+-------------+--------+
items:
+---------+-----------+------------+
| item_id | item_name | item_descr |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       1 | item1     | its item1  |
|       2 | item2     | it's item2 |
|       3 | item3     | it`s item3 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
items_orders:
    +----------+---------+
    | order_id | item_id |
    +----------+---------+
    |        1 |       1 |
    |        1 |       2 |
    |        2 |       2 |
    |        2 |       3 |
    +----------+---------+
```

they are pretty simple, as you can see

could anyone please tell me the query I could use to select all items purchased by customers?

For example:

```
customer|item
1         1
1         2
2         2
2         3
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are asking us the logic to build query. try it your self. Share your query . then we can provide solution. without any efford this site didnt allow us to help :)

Comment: I tried a bunch of queries, but they were all bad :)
Anyway, It's my first stackoverflow question - until now I always used someone's questions and answers
Thank you for your advice, I'll consider posting my efforts next time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT o.customer_id AS customer ,io.id AS item 
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN item_orders io ON io.order_id = o.order_id
```

Comment: Thank you a lot.
I did not think it was that simple.
I promise to think harder next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM orders AS O, items AS I, items_orders AS CON WHERE O.order_id = CON.order_ID AND CON.item_id = I.item_id
```